# Spring @ResponseBody socket exception

Tags: json, spring, exception, response

In the midst of a @ResponseBody response from a Spring 3.2 controller, it seems the client is ending the connection.  They are not listening, so the socket exception below is thrown.  Usually a client socket exception is something we don't bother to log, since it is typically frequent and does not contribute information for us to log these events.

Since it in Spring framework code at that point, how would you suggest catching and ignoring the socket exception?

```
ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:98)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1020)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1730)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:194)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:189)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1148)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:985)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
```